# Не работает align-items center [FLEXBOX]

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Не работает свойство `align-items:center,` 4 блока выстроились сверху, хотя не понимаю в чем проблема. Буду очень рад помощи, спасибо!

```css
.advantages {
  width:100%;
  height:240px;
  background-color: #10c9c3;
}
.wrap-advantages {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}
.adv-item {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  width:240px;
  min-width: 165px;
  height:45px;
  background-color: #cec;
}
```

```html
<section class="advantages"> 
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="wrap-advantages">
      <div class="adv-item">
        <div class="adv-icon">
          <i class="pe-7s-portfolio pe-3x pe-va"></i>
        </div> 
        <div class="adv-content">
          <p>548</p>
          <p>projects completed</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-2</div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-3</div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не работает потому что нужно задать фиксированную высоту для `.wrap-advantages`:

```css
.advantages {
  width:100%;
  
  background-color: #10c9c3;
}
.wrap-advantages {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
  height:240px;
}
.adv-item {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  width:240px;
  min-width: 165px;
  height:45px;
  background-color: #cec;
}
```

```html
<section class="advantages"> 
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="wrap-advantages">
      <div class="adv-item">
        <div class="adv-icon">
          <i class="pe-7s-portfolio pe-3x pe-va"></i>
        </div> 
        <div class="adv-content">
          <p>548</p>
          <p>projects completed</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-2</div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-3</div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Или вот так тогда (всем внутренним наследовать высоту родителя):

```css
.advantages {
  width:100%;
  
  background-color: #10c9c3;
  height:240px;
}

.advantages>.container {
  height:100%;
}
.wrap-advantages {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  
  height:100%;
}
.adv-item {
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  width:240px;
  min-width: 165px;
  height:45px;
  background-color: #cec;
}
```

```html
<section class="advantages"> 
  <div class="container"> 
    <div class="wrap-advantages">
      <div class="adv-item">
        <div class="adv-icon">
          <i class="pe-7s-portfolio pe-3x pe-va"></i>
        </div> 
        <div class="adv-content">
          <p>548</p>
          <p>projects completed</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-2</div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-3</div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.advantages {
  width: 100%;
  height: 240px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #10c9c3;
}

.wrap-advantages {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.adv-item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 240px;
  min-width: 165px;
  height: 45px;
  background-color: #cec;
}
```

```html
<section class="advantages">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-advantages">
      <div class="adv-item">
        <div class="adv-icon">
          <i class="pe-7s-portfolio pe-3x pe-va"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="adv-content">
          <p>548</p>
          <p>projects completed</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-2</div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-3</div>
      <div class="adv-item">block-4</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Потому что высота div с флексом не задана. Задайте ему высоту, либо секции дайте флекс и используйте align-items.

Answer (score -1):

В данном случае `.container` и `.wrap-advantages` должны иметь `height: 100%`.